# Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object ERROR after upgrading to Babel 7

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

Getting the following error after upgrading to Babel 7 in my react app.
Let me know if I need to include more details!

I've tried the solution of replacing `module.exports` with `export default` but that brings other errors.

Error:

```
module.exports = {
^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

  23 | const host = process.env.RAZZLE_HOST || `http://localhost:${port}`;
  24 | 
> 25 | module.exports = {
  26 |   port,
  27 |   host,
  28 |   isAdminSite,
```

config.js context:

```
const host = process.env.RAZZLE_HOST || `http://localhost:${port}`;

module.exports = {
  port,
  host,
  isAdminSite,
  adminSiteUrl,
  userSiteUrl,
```

Imported like:

````
import _ from 'lodash';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import splitLinks from '../helpers/split-links';
import { host } from '../config';
import MatchView from './match_view';```
````

Comment: How are you importing the file?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Editted, does that provide enough context? Sorry, I'm pretty new to this all.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, You can mix `require` and `export`.

```
export {
 someObj
}
//and then import by

require('./file.js')
```

But you cannot mix: `import` with `module.exports` it won't work.

So, in your case, the `module.exports` needs to be `export` or `import` needs to be `require`.

Comment: Can I not use `export default` with `import`? 
`export` alone doesn't seem to recognize the block of code correctly, and weirdly messes with the brace pairings, even though they are correct.

Comment: Yeah yeah, sure you can use `export` also `export default`. But not `module.exports`

Comment: After using `export default`, the server starts for a moment then breaks with this error: 
`./src/common/stores/event.js
Attempted import error: 'host' is not exported from '../config'.`

Comment: If you want to use `export default` then use `import config from './config'` then use `config.host`